# How to make the user not able of making lines using Enter, but only when there is a input?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently making a small game, and i want in my game that the user cannot make lines by clicking the Enter key, only when there is a input.

Is it possible to make this, and if so how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by “make lines?”

Comment: If you run some code in the Interactive Console, and clicking Enter would make lines,

Comment: Please show your existing code, and we can see what's going wrong.